# How do I toggle a class to show which tab is active in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have created two tabs, which I would like the class of active set on the first `<li>` by default.

Then, when the second tab is selected, the .active class should pass to the second `<li>` and be removed from the first.

I can use CSS to create some style rules in order to give a visual indicator as to which tab is currently active.

I have also created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60nz35v9/1/) to see the current output.

Any help welcome as I am rather stuck.

```
<ul class="overlay-panel-actions-primary">
    <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" @click="currentTab = index">{{tab}}</li>
</ul>
<div class="content-bd">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div v-show="currentTab === 0">
            List of filters options
        </div>
        <div v-show="currentTab === 1">
            List of sort options
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            currentTab: 0,
            tabs: ['Filter', 'Sort']
        };
    },
})
```

Comment: You can use the `.exact-active-class` class in your styles, no need to do anything in your JS or JSX

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this -

> :class="{active: currentTab === index}"

```
<li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" @click="currentTab = index" :class="{active: currentTab === index}">{{tab}}</li>
```

Let me know if it works.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/so3mf8h9/

---

**Update**

You can also use ternary operator, It should also work.

```
:class="currentTab === index ? 'active' : ''"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: *Ah, sorry I thought you were using vue-router. When your site gets bigger, it may be an idea to start using router, and when you do, this method will work for you*

---

**Vue has this functionality built in**

All you need to do is add this into your stylesheet

```
.router-link-exact-active {
    // Your styles go here
    border: 5px dashed red;
}
```

Reference: [Vue documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact-active-class)

Here's an example of how I implemented it in a Vue site I made a couple weeks back: [Markup](https://github.com/Lissy93/alicia-sykes-website/blob/master/src/components/NavBar.vue#L24), and [Styles](https://github.com/Lissy93/alicia-sykes-website/blob/master/src/styles/navbar-styles.scss#L94). Hope that helps, let me know if you've got any more questions on implementing this

Comment: Thank you Alicia for being helpful. Much appriciated. Not sure how to get your method working for my tabs as I am not using routing here.

Comment: Yeah, my bad sorry didn't read question properly ;)  I've updated my answer

Comment: OK. Great. I will go with @Siddharths method for this problem, but thanks for the heads up on the routing for now. Very kind of you.